# Insert Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I am learning WordPress plugin development. I need to insert Custom Post Type. I registered custom post type using `register_post_type()`. I am getting below Form when I would like to insert a New Csutom Post Types (News).

[image: News]

**How can I customize this Form ?**

I would like to add some radio buttons and text fields here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to add extra information fields, and settings for individual posts - single posts in CPT - Custom Post Types.

Out of the box, WordPress gives us -

1. ‘title’
2. ‘editor’ (content)
3. ‘author’
4. ‘thumbnail’ (featured image, current theme must also support
   post-thumbnails)
5. ‘excerpt’
6. ‘trackbacks’
7. ‘custom-fields’
8. ‘comments’ (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
9. ‘revisions’ (will store revisions)
10. ‘page-attributes’ (menu order, hierarchical must be true to show
    Parent option)
11. ‘post-formats’ add post formats, see Post Formats

**Actual Answer**

WordPress Team is very aware that you might want to add additional fields and that is where **custom fields/meta box comes** in.

You can use 'custom-fields' that also WordPress gives us but that is not that much intuitive. Rather people in general use metabox. You can go through this article to get a clear idea how metabox works - [what is metabox and how to use it in WordPress](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/)

But it is something like reinventing the wheel. You can have some great solutions to your problem. And that is some plugin that you can include in your theme or plugin in no cost.

There are some popular metabox for you to inlcude in your themes or plugin.
[CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2), [Carbon fields](https://carbonfields.net/), [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/), [metabox.io](https://docs.metabox.io/introduction/) and many more.

But I would recommend or personally like carbon fields to include in the plugin or theme.